# Obtain key of a hashmap with a range of numbers as value

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap<Integer, Float>` with entries:

```
 1 -> 0.127
 2 -> 0.167
 3 -> 0.207
 4 -> 0.247
 5 -> 0.237
 6 -> 0.327
 7 -> 0.367
 8 -> 0.407
 9 -> 0.447
10 -> 0.487
11 -> 0.527
12 -> 0.567
13 -> 0.607
14 -> 0.647
15 -> 0.652
```

Let suppose that I want the key to the Float 0.465 (which is not an existing value). `0.465` is between `0.447` and `0.487`, so I would like to get the key `10`.

The first thought that came in my mind was achive this with 15 if/else if statements or with the switch statement. But in my view, this wouldn't be very elegant and practical.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Reverse your map and use [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html).

Comment: I'd just have a List of Floats.  Reading 15 floats would be quick enough.

Comment: I see that the values are "sorted" to the relation of keys.
Do you really need a HashMap? Looking at this example I see that keys are `index` of a `List`/`Array` + 1 and values are the values under that index.

Comment: Do you have duplicates in your values? And, are your values ordered or not?

Comment: Is this the only case? Or an example?

Comment: There's no mathematical relation between the Key and the value. And yes, the values are always sorted.

Comment: @Bubletan No, This is just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Map is not the appropriate data structure. Use a `TreeSet` instead:

```
TreeSet<Float> numbers = new TreeSet<>();
// populate the set with your numbers, in any order, then

int index = numbers.headSet(n).size() + 1;
```

This will perform very well: TreeSet finds the insertion point in O(log n) time (like a binary search) and the list returned is just a *view* (a new list is not created), so the whole operation is lightweight.

Also note that the elements don't need to be added in any particular order - TreeSet internally maintains their order so searching is fast.

---

Here's some test code:

```
TreeSet<Float> numbers = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(
    0.607F, 0.647F, 0.127F, 0.167F, 0.207F, 0.247F, 0.237F, 0.327F,
    0.367F, 0.407F, 0.447F, 0.487F, 0.527F, 0.567F, 0.652F));
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: `headSet(n).size()` is `O(n)`. This approach is useful only if the number of elements is not too big. Just a suggestion to add to your answer :) And storing floats in the set will work only if there are no duplicates ;)

Comment: Definitively the simplest and most effective and clean solution. I took just about 2 minutes to adapt it to my code.

Comment: @Federico `headSet().size()` is O(1). It returns the size of the backing `NavigableMap`, which is an int field of TreeMap. The creation of the sub list could be order n though... if I have time I'll dig deeper.

Comment: @Bohemian That is true for TreeSet, however the views returned by headSet and tailSet implement size() in O(n) by traversing the returned view and incrementing a counter for each element.

Comment: @Bohemian However creation of tailSet and headSet views is O(1).

Comment: @Federico I debugged my JDK and `size()` returned the field `int size` from the internal impl (in TreeSet) of a NavigableMap - I'm sure it's O(1) (noting that this code uses TreeSet). In which case, based on your finding on headSet, this code is overall O(1). Please do let me know if I have that wrong about size - I am using java 8 if that matters.

Comment: @Bohemian I'm also using java8. TreeSet is backed by a TreeMap instance. TreeSet's size() delegates to TreeMap's size(). TreeSet's headSet() delegates to TreeMap's headMap(). TreeMap's headMap() creates and returns an AscendinSubMap (which is a non-public final inner class) that is backed by the actual TreeMap and is given the bounds of the view in its constructor. AscendingSubMap is a subclass of NavigableSubMap, which is a non-public abstract inner class and is also given the bounds of the view in its constructor, along with the backing map (which happens to be the enclosing instance)...

Comment: In NavigableSubMap, size() is overriden and delegates to entrySet().size(). entrySet() is overriden in AscendingSubMap and returns an AscendingEntrySetView. AscendingEntrySetView is a subclass of EntrySetView, which is an abstract inner class of NavigableSubMap. Finally, the size() method is overriden there (in EntrySetView) and is implemented the way I said: it gets an iterator that increments a counter per each consumed element, until hasNext() returns false. Then that counter is returned.

Comment: As TreeSet's headSet() operation might have been invoked with a key that lies between the first and second element (according to TreeSet's order), then incrementing the counter and invoking next() on that very deep inner class' iterator will happen at most n - 1 times, with n being the size of the TreeSet. And that is O(n). I'm convinced that there's room for improvement in all those view classes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `data` is your initial map and values are unique, you could do:

```
java.util.NavigableMap<Double, Integer> reverseMap = new java.util.TreeMap<>();
for(java.util.Map.Entry<Double, Integer> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    reverseMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
}
System.out.println(reverseMap.ceilingEntry(0.465).getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

If values are always sorted, just use a common array:

```
double[] values = {0.127, ..., 0.652};
```

And then, call the [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-double:A-double-) method, which returns the index of the value that is immediately greater than the given value.

Please note that this approach supports duplicate values, and the index returned is `0-based`.